# OSX EL CAPITAN ONLY - Popup appears offset when I move the ownerNode

Tags: macos, javafx, popup, coordinates, onmouseover

THIS PROBLEM OCCURS ONLY ON OSX EL CAPITAN

There's a ListView, and when the user puts the mouse over a ListCell a popup with a picture related to the 'pointed' item should appear next to the cell.

FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="572.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxswingapplication0.AddController">
 <children>
  <TextField fx:id="textField" onKeyReleased="#oneKeyReleasedTextField" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="499.0">
     <HBox.margin>
        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
     </HBox.margin>
  </TextField>
  <Button fx:id="myButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button">
     <HBox.margin>
        <Insets bottom="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
     </HBox.margin>
  </Button>
</children>
</HBox>
```

Controller Class

```
package javafxswingapplication0;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.util.Callback;


public class AddController implements Initializable {
@FXML
TextField textField;
@FXML
Button myButton;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
}    

public void oneKeyReleasedTextField()
{
    Popup resultsList = new Popup();
    Bounds textFieldBounds = textField.localToScreen(textField.getBoundsInLocal());

    ListView lsv = new ListView();
    //add Data
    ArrayList<String> sampleData = new ArrayList<String>(){{
        add("Jamie");
        add("Dyed");
        add("Seth");
    }};
    ObservableList<String> sampleDataObservable = FXCollections.observableArrayList(sampleData);
    lsv.setItems(sampleDataObservable);
    //CellFactory
    lsv.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
            return new CustomCell();
        }
    });
    //Style
    lsv.setStyle("-fx-pref-width: " + textField.getWidth());
    resultsList.getContent().add(lsv);

    resultsList.show(textField, textFieldBounds.getMinX(), textFieldBounds.getMaxY());
}
}

class CustomCell extends ListCell<String>{
@Override
protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (item != null) {
        setText(item);
    } else {
        setText("");
    } 

    ListCell<String> thisCell = this;
    Popup image = new Popup();
    setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler(){
        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            image.getContent().add(new ImageView("http://theletter.co.uk/images/blog/2011/05/jamie-jones.jpg"));
            Bounds thisCellBounds = thisCell.localToScreen(thisCell.getBoundsInLocal());
            image.show(thisCell, thisCellBounds.getMaxX(), thisCellBounds.getMinY());
        }
    });

    setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler(){
        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            image.hide();
        }
    });
}
}
```

It works fine if I don't move the window that contains the ListView.

On the contrary the Popup with the picture is displayed with an unexpected offset: the problem is that Cell's coordinates I get from "thisCell.localToScreen(thisCell.getBoundsInLocal())" aren't exact if I first moved the window.

What could the problem be?

Comment: This works fine for me. Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: @James_D I have edited my question, please tell me if you need more code

Comment: @James_D I tried to run this program on Windows and it works fine, the problem occurs only on OSX

Comment: It works fine for me on OS X. What JDK version are you using?

Comment: @James_D JDK 1.8
Which version of OS X are you running? I am using El Capitan

Comment: I have JDK 1.8.0_60 on OS X 10.9.5 (whatever the name of that is... Mavericks?)

Comment: @James_D Same JDK here (1.8.0_60), but I'm running OS X 10.11